# Keydown event : numpad +,*/ buttons

Tags: vb.net, keydown, calculator

How can I get VB.net to work out that i have pressed +-*/ in Keydown events?
At the moment i am using a Select Case:

```
Select Case e.Key
            'Numpad Numbers Keydown Events'
            Case Key.NumPad0
                Display.Append("0")
                txtAnswer.Text = Display.ToString
            Case Key.NumPad1
                Display.Append("1")
                txtAnswer.Text = Display.ToString
```

However, I can't find a key.  thing to work with the numpad function buttons.

i tried using:

```
Case AscW(Chr(107))
                Display.Append("+")
                txtAnswer.Text = Display.ToString
```

But it didn't work, can anybody help?

Thanks

Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried Key.Add/Key.Subtract/Key.Multiply/Key.Divide?  If that doesn't work (or those don't correspond with the C# .net keys) Try looking for ones prefixed with 'Oem'.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know off the top of my head, but if I had to find out I'd set a break point in the function, run the program and press each of the keys.  That would trigger the break point and I could inspect the e.Key variable with the debugger to learn exactly which key I pressed.

Comment: That is a sound idea Joel, however the watch function doesn't work on "e", it just stays at System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs

Comment: @Nick - It should work on e, and you can add your own items to the watchlist or even just mouse over the variable to see it's value.